# How do I extract the HTTP error code sent from Azure AD using ADAL Objective-C

Tags: http, error-handling, azure-active-directory, adal, http-status-code-429

I'm trying to write an error handler for an iOS app and want to handle errors differently based on HTTP error codes from the Azure AD token service (STS).  For instance, if I get an HTTP 429, I know not to retry the request or if I get an HTTP 500 I may choose to do a retry.

How can I extract this information out of the AD Error provided in ADAL Objective C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not recommend you use the HTTP error codes directly when using our libraries. We provide ADAL error codes that you should use in order to determine the next steps in your application. These wrap both HTTP errors and other errors the library could throw in to one NSError object you can use.

You should check the error domain for `ADAuthenticationErrorDomain` and then match on the error code such as `AD_ERROR_USER_INPUT_NEEDED`

We maintain this error code list in the `ADErrorCodes.h` header file of the SDK along with the description of how the error can occur: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/blob/dev/ADAL/src/public/ADErrorCodes.h

To catch these errors in your code, use the following pattern:

```
[authContext acquireTokenSilentWithResource:...
          completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result) {

if (!result.error) {  

// normal program flow 

} else {

   if ([result.error.domain isEqual:ADAuthenticationErrorDomain] && result.error.code == AD_ERROR_USER_INPUT_NEEDED) {

            // Handle user input needed error

       }

   else if ([result.error.domain isEqual:ADAuthenticationErrorDomain] && result.error.code == AD_ERROR_SERVER_WRONG_USER) {

           // Handle user returned by the server 
           //does not match the the user identifier error

          }
}];
```